# Microsoft chart controls 3.5 compatibility issues with .net 4.0+

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, charts

I made an .net application using VB with a target framework of 3.5. I also use Microsoft's chart control for .net 3.5. The problem is the chart control has compatibility issues with 4.0 and above. Micrsoft listed a fix for it on their website, but when I attempt to launch the application it gives me an error due to their "fix"

Here is the link to the Microsoft fix on their website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990785(v=vs.110).aspx and here's the error I get upon trying to launch the application after applying their fix: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in test.exe

Additional information: An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I understand that it can not seem to find the assembly file, but I have no clue how to fix it. I need help, thanks!

Comment: Can we see your app config?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup>

<runtime>
    
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
   
    </assemblyBinding>
   
  </runtime>


</configuration>

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help but worth a try... change <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.5.0.0-3.5.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0-3.5.0.0"/> and as long as the machine has both .net libraries it may work.